# Sqrt method doesn't return number

Tags: c#, math.sqrt

I've got a method that computes two offsets for something else in my code. I wrote these offsets to the output and the result was: `Isn't number`. When I tryed to assign these values to another variables, these variables' value was 0.

This is my code:

```
int w = 1200;
int h = 1824;
double offsetX = System.Math.Sqrt (-((9 * w * w) / 16));
double offsetY = System.Math.Sqrt (((9 * h * h) / 16) + ((9 * w * w) / 16) - offsetX);
```

I don't know if it is a mathematical or a programming problem. Why does it return this weird value?

Comment: they can't. a square root of a negative number isn't real. its imaginary.

Comment: @DanielA.White OMG. I forgot about that :D. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-((9 * w * w) / 16)` expression returns a negative value which is `-810000`.

That's why this method returns [`NaN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From [the documentation of `Math.Sqrt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

```
d parameter  | Return value
Negative     | NaN
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers);

> The square of any positive or negative number is positive, and the
>   square of 0 is 0. **Therefore, no negative number can have a real square
>   root. However, it is possible to work with a more inclusive set of
>   numbers, called the complex numbers, that does contain solutions to
>   the square root of a negative number.**